# How do you add new "driver.c" files to get built with kernel

Tags: raspbian, kernel, driver

I've been following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) guide to it's entirety when building existing kernel modules with no issues.

My problem arises when I try to add my own driver.c files to the /linux/drivers/input/touchscreen folder (for example).  I can't seem to get the build system to recognize these new files, even when I explicitly add them to the make file.

Normally I configure the modules I want to build through menuconfig

```
make ARCh=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig
```

Then I cross compile on host Linux with:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- modules dtbs
```

but my driver.c file doesn't get compiled.  The build system totally ignores it.  **This is not surprising since the files don't show up in menuconfig**.  Is there a elegant way to 'register' these new files with the build system so I don't have to add them directly to the make file?  But even if I add them to the make file myself, they STILL don't build.  I think I've missed something that should be easy and now I am really confused about what to do.

Comment: Pretty sure menuconfig works with `.Kconfig` files, but you don't need it in order to compile a module; have a look at "Compiling and Loading" in chapter 2 of [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the pointer, I've skimmed through that before but perhaps not closely enough.  Will look into it asap!